# QQuickPaintedItem paint() report error that Timers cannot be stopped from another thread, which seem to cause child threads endless loop?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qgraphicsview

My code is as follows:

```
void DrpltGyslPanel::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    view_->render(painter, boundingRect(), view_->viewport()->rect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
}
```

`DrpltGyslPanel` is subclass of `QQuickPaintedItem`, `view_` is instance of `QGraphicsView` .And I know `DrpltGyslPanel::paint` is called in `QSGRenderThread`, but what is this `Timer` used for?
And this also caused child threads endless loop.
How can I kill timer exactly? Or one more step for what exactly caused child threads endless loop?

--------------------------------added at 2019/12/19

If the `QGraphicsView` shows, endless loop won't appear in the **Release** build and will in the **Debug** build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QGraphicsView::addItem` will start a timer by default interval(2000ms) at [here](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/13e0a36626bd75e631dd9536e795a494432b1945/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsscenebsptreeindex.cpp#L208).`QGraphicsView::render` will kill timer at [here](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/13e0a36626bd75e631dd9536e795a494432b1945/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsscenebsptreeindex.cpp#L125).When killing timer will estimate whether the current thread is thread timer lives to make sure timer usage is in the same thread.So we can not invoke `QGraphicsView::render` in `DrpltGyslPanel::paint` from `QSGRenderThread`.
The code is corrected as follows：

```
void DrpltGyslPanel::update(const QRect &rect)
{
    renderPixman = QPixmap(view_->viewport()->rect().size());//renderPixman is member variable
    QPainter painter(&renderPixman);
    view_->render(&painter, boundingRect(), view_->viewport()->rect(), 
    Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    QQuickPaintedItem::update(rect);
}
```

And why which will caused child threads endless loop, that is `timerEvent` alaways triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, calling render will internally stop a timer which lives in another thread.
You cannot paint on [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) which lives in another thread.
You can ask the `_view` to render itself into a [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) and send it back to `DrpltGyslPanel` using another signal. 
You can also have a [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html) instance in `DrpltGyslPanel`, share it with `_view` and use [QMutex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html) to block those threads from reading or writing the [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html).

Comment: Rendering the `painter` pointer of DrpltGyslPanel will trigger an exception in the main thread.

Comment: Would you please explain more about your goal in your answer?

Comment: Sorry,I has attached it.